# Печать на русском. Принтер TG2480H. VS2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, принтер

Всем привет! Нужна ваша помощь

Уже 4 дня как я пытаюсь напечатать текст на русском языке но все четно.
В принтере используется протокол ESC/POS. Работает через компорт. С горем пополам я нашел класс-обвертку для компорта и научился отправлять команды. И все бы хорошо, но как только дело дошло до русского языка - работа встала. Перечитав протокол я наткнулся на команду "Set charecter code table", что дает возможность выбирать кодировки в самом принтере для правильного отображения языков. Одним из параметров была кодировка РС866, которая и указывает на кириллицу. При подключении этой кодировки должен был заработать русский, но на печати снова появились кракозяблики. Открыв таблицу СР866 я увидел, что эти кракозяблики являются частью таблицы. Взяв коды букв из этой таблицы и отправив их на печать я все таки получил русский язык. А если взять и сравнить коды, например букв 'A', то разница между ними будет - 64. (код 'A' С++ = 192, 'A'CP866 = 128). Интересно то, что при использовании кодировки СР866 для консоли (setConsoleCP, setConsoleCPOut) отображается нормальный русский текст, а при выводе на принтер получаем кракозяблики.

Подскажите, может нужно как-то еще обработать текст? Почему кодировки не совпадают?

Answer (score 2):

Кодовая таблица, используемая «в C++» определяется кодировкой файлов исходных кодов. Скорее всего, Visual Studio сохраняет эти файлы с использованием *Windows 1251*. Следовательно:

- либо укажите Visual Studio использовать кодировку CP866,
- либо укажите принтеру использовать Windows 1251.

Comment: Я провел некоторые тесты и выяснилось, что все таки консоль отображает именно 866, а не 1251. Из этого следует, что подаваемый текст все таки закодирован в 1251. К сожалению на принтере есть только 866. По этому теперь стоит задача конвектировать 1251 в 866. Уже создана тема для этого. если можете помочь, подключайтесь. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/534821/c-utf-8-%D0%B2-cp866

Answer (score 0):

Просто после main() напиши setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");