# C++ UTF-8 в CP866

Tags: c++, кодировка, visual-c++, перекодировка

Пишу библиотеку для принтера. На вход подается текст в формате UTF-8. Принтер печатает кириллицу в формате CP866(кириллица). Как преобразовать UTF-8 в CP866? Возможно есть специальные функции?

Comment: Если это под Windows, сконвертируйте в UTF-16 при помощи MultiByteToWideChar, а потом в CP-866 при помощи WideCharToMultiByte.

Comment: Да, я видел такое решение, но что-то не получилось совсем. Если вам не тяжело, могли бы вы привести простенький пример?

Comment: Я с телефона, напишу пример, когда доберусь до компьютера (если никто другой не напишет тем временем).

Comment: 1. Во входном потоке есть символы, не поддерживаемые CP866? 2. `dwFlags`  в `MultiByteToWideChar` указан (если да, то для UTF-8 функция работать не будет)? 3. `WC_ERR_INVALID_CHARS` нигде не встречается?

Comment: 1. Нет, чисто русский язык. 2. dwFlags = 0. Но на самом деле, я думаю, что просто что-то не правильно делаю. По этому и не получается. Я новенький в с++ (это моя вторая программа). По этому нуждаюсь в простом примере.

Comment: [пример кода как `MultiByteToWideChar()` используется чтобы utf-8 string в wstring и обратно превратить](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3999597/4279). Если вы хотите просто Юникодный текст в консоль напечатать, см. [Как отобразить русский текст?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/372864/23044)

Answer (score 5):

```
ifstream file("text.txt");
char pszCode[30];
file.getline(pszCode, 30);
BSTR    bstrWide;
char   pszAnsi[50];
int     nLength;
char* text = "";

nLength = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, pszCode, strlen(pszCode) + 1, NULL, NULL);
bstrWide = SysAllocStringLen(NULL, nLength);

MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, pszCode, strlen(pszCode) + 1, bstrWide, nLength);

nLength = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_OEMCP, 0, bstrWide, -1, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
WideCharToMultiByte(CP_OEMCP, 0, bstrWide, -1, pszAnsi, nLength, NULL, NULL);
SysFreeString(bstrWide);

cout << pszAnsi << endl;
```

В общем использовал в этот метод, как посоветовал VladD, в принципе все работает, хотя конечно я так и не понял, как работают эти две функции до конца. Но все равно спасибо!